# get latest records from mongodb ,if those two records are same but the time is different

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
{"permit":"1905403","otp":"22","acct":"12556""timestamp":"06/12/2020 14:37:50"}
{"permit":"1905403","otp":"22","acct":"12556","timestamp":"06/12/2020 17:30:50"}

 router.post('/getPermitNumberDetails', async (req, res) => {
try {
    // console.log('req', req.body)
    const permitNumber = req.body.permit
    const permitNumberRelatedInfo = await dukePdf_Model.findOne({ "permit": permitNumber });
    res.status(200).send({ permitNumberRelatedInfo: permitNumberRelatedInfo });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).send(e);
}});
```

In MongoDB collection, I have these two documents,the content is the same but the timestamp is different.i will be having a search bar in UI, when I type permit number as 1905403, there are two records for that particular permit. but I need to show the latest record i.e, with the latest timestamp.i have mentioned the router above..can anyone please help me

Comment: You can use the `find` method (not `findOne`) which returns a [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html). Then use the _sort_ on the cursor (sort descending on _timestamp_ field) and then _limit_ 1.

Comment: thanks prasad_ ,i will give a try